# Insert PHP Echo Value in MySQL Database Table

Tags: php, database

I have a database driven website (dynamic pages) but the content is stored in static files that are included in my pages. I want to scrap these text files and put the content in a database table, but I don't know how to deal with PHP code in the content.

For example, consider the following text:

```
<p>You can learn more at <a href="<?php echo $MySite1; ?>">this website</a>.</p>
```

`$MySite1` might echo `<a href="wwww.mysite1.com">`, but if I put it into a database table, it just displays as plain text.

So does anyone know how I could modify a query like the one below so that PHP code in content stored in field AI. Article will display as PHP code? In other words, I'd like visitors to see `www.mysite1.com`, not `<?php echo $MySite1; ?>`.

Thanks.

```
  $Topics = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT ZT.N, ZT.URL, ZT.Title, ZT.Subtitle, ZT.Parent, ZT.Live, AI.URL, AI.Article
  FROM gz_topics ZT
  LEFT JOIN gz_articles_topics_intro AI ON AI.URL = ZT.URL
  WHERE ZT.URL = '$MyURL' AND ZT.Live = 1"));
```

Comment: Just one comment: bad practice. I wouldn' t put php-code in a database. There are almost no situation where this would be helpful. However you **could** use `eval()` but what you are going for is **bad**!

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a content management system with template abilities. I suggest you find one of these, rather than this ad hoc solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval()` function (http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).  Very dangerous as is shown in that linked page.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. There is another option that I've used which isn't too much of a headache. I can simply replace <?php $EchoValue; ?> with $EchoValue; then use str_replace to replace it with a value...

str_replace('www.mysite.com', '$EchoValue;', $Text);

Based on the tips I've read on this page, I should stick with that, rather than put PHP code in a database. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea for you to work with some light weight and fast template engine...
It could make your life much easier...
Check out "Haanga" for example...

Answer (score 1):

If you planning to use str_replace...
More elegant solution could be just saving your template with %s,and using printf with the arguments needed...

really depends on the usage...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with %s or printf. I found some information about the printf function @ http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_printf.asp but it actually looks far more complicated than my solution. However, I don't understand what "saving your template with %s" means, and that's probably the key to what I'm missing. Thanks.